# Expatriate's Return to China

Tags: china

What steps are necessary for a person born in China, who as an adult has been living in Australia for many years and has Australian Citizenship, who would like to return to China to visit elderly parents.

This person also has a 20 year old son, who would like to accompany his parent, and visit his grandparents. Both Chinese parents were living in Australia when he was born. Following their separation a couple of years ago, the other parent returned to China.

Long term: If they so desired, would it be possible for both to resettle in China?

Comment: Is the question about whether they have Chinese citizenship? or about which Chinese visas they should get?